# Unable to install twisted package on windows machine

Tags: python, windows, twisted

I have got python2.6 installed on my windows machine.

tried to install twisted package but unable to install it.

Also installed the zope interface

On the python interpretor I get the error as :

```
  >>>import twisted
  >>>Import Error: No Module named twisted
```

I installed the package twisted succesfully.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\tazim_kolhar>python
Python 2.6 (r26:66721, Oct  2 2008, 11:35:03) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import twisted
>>> ^Z
```

But when, I try to run the script containing the package :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\tazim_kolhar>cd ..

C:\Documents and Settings>cd ..

C:\>cd Python_scripts


C:\Python_scripts>python aimbot.py
aimbot.py:10: DeprecationWarning: twisted.words.protocols.toc is deprecated sinc
e Twisted 9.0.  Use twisted.words.protocols.oscar instead.
from twisted.words.protocols import toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "aimbot.py", line 10, in <module>
from twisted.words.protocols import toc
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\twisted\words\protocols\toc.py", line 27,
in <module>
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 37, in
<module>
from twisted.internet import selectreactor
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 1
7, in <module>
from zope.interface import implements
ImportError: No module named zope.interface

C:\Python_scripts>
```

I have downloded the zope interface . But the document http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/WindowsBuilds does not clearly explain about the zope interface.

How do I install this zope interface ?

Any help will be valuable .

Thanks,
Tazim.

Comment: how did you try to install it?

Comment: downloaded the  .msi file executed it . allowed to install in a folder c:\twisted  . the on python interpreter executed >>>import twisted . I get Import Error

Comment: the text you copied and pasted from your python interpreter says that you are running python 2.6 when you succeed importing the package. however, you tell us that you are running 2.7 in the first sentence... which version is installed ? which version is the default one ? which version are you running when you get the error ?

Comment: @adrien, thanx for pointing out the mistake . The default version is python 2.6

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The steps to install the package are as follows :

1. Install python any version .
2. Then, Install the appropriate exe

   http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads

   Twisted 10.1.0 for Python 2.6 ( msi |  exe) or Twisted 10.1.0 for Python 2.5 ( msi |  exe)
3. download the zope interface .

   http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads
4. Install setuptools

   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads

   Update the PATH variable to the subdirectory containing easy_install.exe .
5. install zope interface using :

   `easy_install zope.interface-3.6.1-py2.5-win32.egg`

Comment: I have installed twisted according to your instruction now can you please tell me how to varify tht its being installed successfully and where can i find twistd command

Comment: python
>>> import twisted
>>> print twisted.version
[twisted, version 13.0.2]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for building Twisted on Windows is [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/WindowsBuilds). Follow that and you should not face any problem.

Since the import fails, clearly something is not right, so you should follow the steps in the manual above.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed Twisted-12.3.0 using the .msi download.

For the zope interface I extracted the archive (zope.interface-4.0.3-py2.7-win32.egg) and moved the extracted zope directory into the python/lib directory.

I got the usage message when running trial.py in a command window.

(I thought I saw some issue with 64 bit windows and setuptools????)